# How to add IBluetoothA2dp.aidl interface to my project?

Tags: android, import, bluetooth, headset

I'm using android version 2.2 and I cant find `android.bluetooth.IBluetoothA2dp` in the `bluetooth` sub-package `android.bluetooth`.
Do I have to upgrade to a higher version for this file to be available. Or what else should I do so I could be able to implement this interface to use it in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why you need `IBluetoothA2dp` and not the `BluetoothA2dp`. But the `IBluetoothA2dp` interface is a hidden interface (see [here](http://codesearch.google.com/codesearch#Ub44q3wMVa4/trunk/AndroidSDK/src/android/bluetooth/IBluetoothA2dp.java&q=IBluetoothA2DP&type=cs&l=9)). At least up to Android 3.0 (not including).

As for `BluetoothA2dp` class it was publicly introduced in API Level 11 (Honeycomb, Android 3.0). It was first introduced in Android as earlier as API Level 3 and marked as hidden. Then it was dramatically changed in API Level 5 at still was marked as hidden. And officially released only in API Level 11.

You can use reflection to access that class on earlier platforms, but that's a tricky and not recommended way.

Comment: So, theoretically speaking, I can implement the whole BluetoothA2dp connection thread using reflection, wright?

Comment: Yes, you can. It will be challenging, but possible. I did something similar with `BluetoothHeadset`. But, well, its not something I would recommend in production application.